# how to adapt jquery to `@media (max-width)`

Tags: jquery, html, css

My 2 `div` animate thank to my jquery script below. When screen is less than `700px`, `div` becaome smaller square (`35px` instead of `50px`). I want`.animate({width:100px});` to animate to `70px` only when screen is less than `700px`. For that, I need to incorporate a new variable in my jquery script, which takes into consideration whether `@media (max-width:700px)` is in place or not. But I haven't found the way to do it. Help! :)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$(".rightSocial a").hover(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({width:"100px"});
        $(this).find('span').stop().animate({"margin-left":"50px"});
      },
      function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({width:"50px"});
        $(this).find('span').stop().animate({"margin-left":"0"});
      });
     
     
     
    });
```

```css
.rightSocial {
    height:300px;
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    top:100px;
    
  }
  
  .rightSocial a {
    display:block;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    margin-top:1px;
  }
  
  .twitterCont {
    background:red;
    position:relative;
  }
  
  .FBCont {
    background:blue;
    position:relative;
  }
  
  .rightTwitter {
    height:40px;
    width:50px;
    background:yellow;
    background-size:contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:0;
  }
  
  .rightFB {
    height:40px;
    width:50px;
    background:red;
    background-size:contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:0;
  }

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  
  .rightSocial {
  width:35px;
}

 .rightSocial a {
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
 }
 
 .rightTwitter, .rightFB {
   height:30px;
    width:30px;
 }
  
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rightSocial">
    <div>Share</div>
    <a href="#" class="twitterCont"><span class="rightTwitter" title="Twitter"></span></a>
    <a href="#" class="FBCont"><span class="rightFB" title="Facebook"></span></a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ypy9mge4/1) is a live demo of it. I'm used `$( window ).width()` to get width of window and then just have simple `if` statement. Also I setup for `span` for `10px` less `margin-left` for displays which less then `700px`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$(".rightSocial a").hover(function(){
     if ($( window ).width() <= 700) {
            $(this).stop().animate({width:"70px"});
            $(this).find('span').stop().animate({"margin-left":"40px"});
        }
     else {
            $(this).stop().animate({width:"100px"});
            $(this).find('span').stop().animate({"margin-left":"50px"});
        }
      },
      function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({width:"50px"});
        $(this).find('span').stop().animate({"margin-left":"0"});
      });
     
     
     
    });
```

```css
.rightSocial {
    height:300px;
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    top:100px;
    
  }
  
  .rightSocial a {
    display:block;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    margin-top:1px;
  }
  
  .twitterCont {
    background:red;
    position:relative;
  }
  
  .FBCont {
    background:blue;
    position:relative;
  }
  
  .rightTwitter {
    height:40px;
    width:50px;
    background:yellow;
    background-size:contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:0;
  }
  
  .rightFB {
    height:40px;
    width:50px;
    background:red;
    background-size:contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:0;
  }

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  
  .rightSocial {
  width:35px;
}

 .rightSocial a {
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
 }
 
 .rightTwitter, .rightFB {
   height:30px;
    width:30px;
 }
  
  }
```

```html
<div class="rightSocial">
    <div>Share</div>
    <a href="#" class="twitterCont"><span class="rightTwitter" title="Twitter"></span></a>
    <a href="#" class="FBCont"><span class="rightFB" title="Facebook"></span></a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using jQuery, you might want to check out the `resize()` event coupled with the `width()` function.

Something like...

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if( $(window).width() < 700 ) {
        // magic
    }
}
```